# Effect hook for displaying initial data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I have the default `App` function that react provides on create.

I'm trying to fetch some data for the initial display:

```
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/restApiTest").then(res => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let array_people = data.map((p) => {
                return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName;
            });
            setPeople(array_people);
        });
    }, []);
```

the problem is that this data is only rendered when I re-render a subcomponent. How can I load initial data?

I tried to follow [React Effect Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [React State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

**Edit**: Adding the rest of the function

```
function App() {
    // const people = ["Arnaud", "Etienne", "Riccardo", "Ed", "Jose"];
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
    const [filtered, setFiltered] = useState(people);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/restApiTest").then(res => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(data => {
            let array_people = data.map((p) => {
                return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName;
            });
            setPeople(array_people);
        });
    }, []);


    console.log(people);

    const filterPeople = (data) => {
        let filters = people.filter((name) => {
            return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(data.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });
        setFiltered(filters);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>
                <SearchBar onEnter={filterPeople}/>
                <SortableList people={filtered}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: initial load was good https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-star-bmor3

Comment: @prasanth maybe it has something to do with the `fetch` call?

Comment: may be ..please check the then data console.

Comment: for above code `console.log(people);` its immediate  call from `App` function.please console inside the `useffect` on then function after setPeople call .Because its execute before fetch finish

Comment: It's empty, what's going on?

Comment: which one ? `immediate console.log(people);` or `then(data`

Comment: calling `console.log(people)` after `setpeople`

Comment: check the  `array_people` in fetch response .please console and check it

Comment: It's populated, man. The problem is with the render I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the *useEffect's* callback is setting your `people` state with the fetched data the `filtered` state still remains the same i.e. `[]` and not as per the new `people` state. It's just on the initial mount that your `filtered` state would be set to `people` state and not on every subsequent rerender as what you are expecting I presume. To update the `filtered` state with the fetched data you have to call the `setFiltered` function explicitly in the useEffect, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/restApiTest")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
         let array_people = data.map((p) => {
             return p.firstName + ' ' + p.lastName;
         });
         setPeople(array_people);
         setFiltered(array_people)
      });
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thing is my data is only fetched once, so there are no changes to `people` state after the initial load, can it be done?

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. React takes care of that optimization. As you can see this new `useEffect` has a dependency on just the `people` state. So, it would fire only the number of times the `people` state would change. If `people` changes only once, it would fire only once and not anymore. PS useEffects are also fired on initial mounts as well so it would fire 2 times to be exact in the entire lifecycle of your component. :)

Comment: Your solution works but had to call the `filterPeople()` passing an empty string as a parameter. I'm just concerned that in the case of a more performance heavy function, having to call it for the render might not be ideal.

Comment: In that case, please refer to the updated answer. :)